# System sounds but no other sounds when use headphones

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, bugs, headphones, sony-xperia-z5

I plugged in my headphones this morning,  which were working fine yesterday,  and went to try and watch a video only for there to be no sound.

But all notifications and click events seem to be making sound as usual. And only certain apps seem to be not making sound.

Thinking it was possibly a bug in YouTube, I tried running other apps:

- Spotify: no sound
- Google calendar notification :**full sound**
- Hearthstone, a game : no sound
- Analogue Synthesiser emulator: **full sound**
- ZType,  a game: **full sound**
- Shadowrun returns, a game: no sound
- BBC iPlayer: no sound
- Sony Xperia Podcast app: no sound
- Pointless,  a game: no sound.

I've yet to test with other headphones. But have tried a restart and tried double checking the volume control advanced settings.

Any idea what the reason is?

If it was all sounds or only loud sounds it would be simple,  but it's not,  which is what confuses me.

*further testing*

After I got to a desktop PC did some further tests:

- tested same sources with a different set of headphones,  same result.
- tested the original set on the desktop PC,  produce sound from all sources no problem.
- Set phone to safe mode to see if it would be an app which has a damaging bug after update (as I've set my phone to update when on wifi and charging, so it is plausible) the behaviour was the same.

Comment: Bee, the Headphones I currently use have never been detected by smart connect,  I think it's because they have a detachable cable, They're a set of shure headphones.

Comment: Well,  the phone is still under warranty (but not insured) do you believe this could be an issue that is viable for sending it back to Sony at no extra cost?

Comment: I never dealt with Sony but yes IMO, this warrants exchange. For starters you could post on their support site and if it helps, it could save you the trouble of sending back

Comment: Soundabout didn't have any effect

Comment: I had a problem with headsets and Skype on an Xperia z3 a while back. And then I found out order matters: the headphone needed to be plugged in before opening the app. Another potential cause: SONY tries to be clever and detect different headsets. In the sound settings, there is an option to select "generic headset" (don't know for the Z5, but probably similar)

Comment: Nah, no such setting in z5, probably because it was too buggy. 
 There's the option to have the z5 use headphone plug in to trigger events and a switch in setings to turn on ClearSound™ but there's no detection which changes sound settings unless I tell it to (which I haven't.)

Comment: Xperia Support are literally useless.

I told them the specific problem, but because it had a 1mm bend in the phone, they refused to repair the problem. 

And then gave me the option of paying £25 to get it back unrepaired, £280 to get it replaced (which is 70 more than the phone costs) or they'd recycle it for free.